modules/alpn-impl/alpn-1.8.0_202.mod not found
Old jetty installation (jetty-9.4.3.v20170317 - 17 March 2017) is missing the JDK specific mod file modules/alpn-impl/alpn-1.8.0_202.mod not found. We use java version "1.8.0_202". How do I get this file?
WARN  : Deprecated [name] used in ${jetty.base}/modules/logging.mod
WARN  : Deprecated [name] used in ${jetty.base}/modules/webapp-logging.mod
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read file: modules/alpn-impl/alpn-1.8.0_202.mod
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Modules.registerModule(Modules.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Modules.enable(Modules.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Modules.enable(Modules.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Modules.enable(Modules.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.processCommandLine(Main.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)

alpn-impl contains the following mod files
/opt/jetty# ls -l modules/alpn-impl/
total 112
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  169 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  169 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_05.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  223 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_101.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  223 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_102.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  169 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_11.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  223 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_111.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  227 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_112.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  227 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_121.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  227 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_131.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  229 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_151.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  169 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_20.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  169 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_25.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  169 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_31.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  223 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_40.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  223 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_45.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  223 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_51.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  223 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_60.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  223 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_65.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  223 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_66.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  223 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_71.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  223 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_72.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  223 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_73.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  223 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_74.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  223 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_77.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  223 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_91.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  223 Dec 17  2017 alpn-1.8.0_92.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty 1111 Dec 17  2017 alpn-8.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  135 Dec 17  2017 alpn-9.mod

The above jetty installation worked while using
java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"

but we are running into this issue after migrating to
java -version
java version "1.8.0_202"


"Old jetty installation" Questions should be specific. Which exact version of Jetty?

@aled I have updated the ticket with the version

Eclipse Jetty 9.4.x is at End of Life, you should be using a supported version of Jetty at this point in time.  Which would be Jetty 12.  If you need to stick with javax.servlet (and not the newer jakarta.servlet) use the ee8 environment on Jetty 12.   For ALPN to work on today's browsers, you must use Java 8u252 or newer and Jetty 9.4.37.v20210219 or newer.

Posting as an answer instead.
NOTICE: Eclipse Jetty 9.4.x is at End of Life, you should be using a supported version of Jetty at this point in time. Which would be Jetty 12. If you need to stick with javax.servlet (and not the newer jakarta.servlet) use the ee8 environment on Jetty 12.
For ALPN and Jetty 9 to work on today's browsers, you must:

use Java 8u252 or newer.
use Jetty 9.4.37.v20210219 or newer.

